# calling a helper method for parent's constructor with fields defined in child

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I am having a problem instantiating a child object using its parent constructor. The constructor calls its helper method but I want the variables used in that method to be child's fields.

I'm not sure this makes sense, so I put simplified version of the classes below. Basically it's a simple Java program that simulates air traffic. As the program handles several types of plane, a parent class (Plane) was created along with some children classes that correspond to each type. At the moment a Factory class (PlaneFactory) is used to generate a one of the types of plane depending on a probability.

When a plane is created, an id and timestamp are assigned. Another thing which needs to be done is to set its remaining fuel time. This is done in the helper method, generateInitialFuelTime() which is called in the Plane constructor. The method returns a random number between min and max values. Each type of planes has different min and max values, so when generateProbability() is called, I wanted it to make it use minFuelTime and maxFuelTime values defined as fields in children class but it seems to be looking at its parent's at the moment (which is null).

I thought about making generateInitialFuelTime() or setting minFuelTime & maxFuelTime values as parameters of the constructor, but not quite sure if it's the best way.

**PlaneFactory class**:

```
public class PlaneFactory {
    public Plane getPlane(int id, Time time){
        Plane plane = null;
        double probability = generateProbability();
        if (0.5 > probability) {
            plane = new Type1Plane();
        } else if (0.2 > probability) {
            plane = new Type2Plane();
        }
        return plane;
    }
    private double generateProbability() {
        // This method returns a probability between 0 and 1
    }
}
```

**Plane class** (Parent class):

```
public class Plane{
    protected int id;
    protected Time initialRemainingFuelTime;
    protected Time initializedTime;
    protected int minFuelTime;
    protected int maxFuelTime;

    public Parent(int id, Time currentTime) {
        this.id = id;
        initializedTime = currentTime;
        initialFuelTime = generateInitialFuelTime();
    }

    protected Time generateInitialFuelTime() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int min = getMinFuelTime().getMinute() + 1;
        int range = getMaxFuelTime().getMinute() - getMinFuelTime().getMinute();
        int initialFuelTime = r.nextInt(min) + range;
        return new Time (0, randomMinute , 0);
    }

    protected Time getMinFuelTime() {
          return minFuelTime;
    }

    protected Time getMaxFuelTime() {
          return maxFuelTime;
    }
```

**Type1Plane class** (Child class):

```
public class Type1Plane extends Plane{
    private int minFuelTime = new Time(0, 20, 0) // 20 minute
    private int maxFuelTime = new Time(0, 40, 0) // 40 minute

    public Type2Plane (int id, Time currentTime) {
        super(id, currentTime);
    }
}
```

**Type2Plane class** (Child class):

```
public class Type2Plane extends Plane{
    private int minFuelTime = new Time(0, 10, 0) // 10 minute
    private int maxFuelTime = new Time(0, 20,0) // 20 minute

    public Type2Plane (int id, Time currentTime) {
        super(id, currentTime);
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have a good solution for this problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sorry I think there is a flaw in generating Type2Plane in PlaneFactory, but please ignore it. I hope you get the idea anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply override `getMinFuelTime` and `getMaxFuelTime` in your child classes, as such:

```
public class Type1Plane extends Plane{
    private Time minFuelTime = new Time(0, 20, 0) // 20 minute
    private Time maxFuelTime = new Time(0, 40, 0) // 40 minute

    public Type2Plane (int id, Time currentTime) {
        super(id, currentTime);
    }

    protected Time getMinFuelTime() {
          return minFuelTime;
    }

    protected Time getMaxFuelTime() {
          return maxFuelTime;
    }
}
```

And the same goes for Type2Plane.

Now, if `Plane` class should never be instantiated on its own, then make it `abstract` and the get methods as well (and remove the variables):

```
public abstract class Plane{
    protected int id;
    protected Time initialRemainingFuelTime;
    protected Time initializedTime;

    public Parent(int id, Time currentTime) {
        this.id = id;
        initializedTime = currentTime;
        initialFuelTime = generateInitialFuelTime();
    }

    protected Time generateInitialFuelTime() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int min = getMinFuelTime().getMinute() + 1;
        int range = getMaxFuelTime().getMinute() - getMinFuelTime().getMinute();
        int initialFuelTime = r.nextInt(min) + range;
        return new Time (0, randomMinute , 0);
    }

    protected abstract Time getMinFuelTime();
    protected abstract Time getMaxFuelTime();

}
```

By the way, please note that there seems to be some inconsistency with your variables, you treat Time variables as int or vise-versa.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override getMinFuelTime and getMaxFuelTime methods in the child classes.

Answer (score 0):

Since subclasses are initialized after parent class you can't rely on fields of a subclass in a superclass constructor.

What you can do is provide a custom behavior through an `abstract` method, so basically

```
private int minFuelTime = new Time(0,20,0);
protected Time getMinFuelTime() { return minFuelTime; }
```

becomes:

```
class Planet {
    protected abstract Time getMinFuelTime();
}

class Type1Plane extends Planet {
    @Override
    protected Time getMinFuelTime() { return new Time(0,20,0); }
}
```

This is allowed since at this point there is no "missing hole" that need to be initialized by the subclass since the implementation will be present in any case when initializing the parent.